# Using Live ID for authentication in a Silverlight 4 Out of Browser App

Tags: authentication, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser, windows-live-id

Is it possible to use Live ID for authentication in a Silverlight 4 Out of Browser App.

If it is do you know of any sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can find some solution at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices

Comment: I had looked there and unfortunatly it does'nt seem to have SL4 out of browser as an option.